# Is there a teminal command to get the most recently created file or folder?

Tags: command-line

I often need to do something like `command most_recently_created_file_or_folder` from the terminal. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't know of any such command, but you could possibly query gnome-recently-used (sorry I don't have a link to docs on that) to find files most recently created by apps in GNOME.

Comment: Can you give us more context for what you're trying to do? There might be a better solution.

Comment: I'm trying to open the most recently created file with nzbget

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're running Zeitgeist you could use the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from zeitgeist.client import ZeitgeistDBusInterface
from zeitgeist.datamodel import Event, Interpretation, TimeRange, \
 StorageState, ResultType

zg = ZeitgeistDBusInterface()
events = zg.FindEvents(
 TimeRange.always(),
 [Event.new_for_values(interpretation=Interpretation.CREATE_EVENT)],
 StorageState.Any, 1, ResultType.MostRecentEvents)

last_event = Event(events[0])
last_subject = last_event.get_subjects()[0]

print last_subject.uri
```

Comment: could you provide sources to learn how to use the API this way?

Comment: Hi Benjamin. You can find the documentation for Zeitgeist's Python API at http://zeitgeist-project.com/docs/0.8.2/. If there is interest I may write some easier to understand tutorial blog posts.

Comment: As a follow up, I did write a tutorial here: http://bloc.eurion.net/archives/2012/zeitgeist-python-api-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `find` command, or [fileschanged](http://fileschanged.sourceforge.net/) if you need to do it dynamically. The answers to [a similar recent question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8971/creating-a-directory-of-recently-created-files) may also help.

Answer (score 1):

The command `history` will print a list of the last (500 or so depending on the settings) commands that were executed in the shell.

you can do `history |grep mkdir` to search for any new directories made. However it will only work if the directory was made explicitly (i.e. by the user) and in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
command "`ls -c1 | head -n1`"
```

will run `command` on the most recently created file in the current working directory. Different quoting or escaping may be required for your shell.